# Using mutate(across(...)) with purrr::map

Tags: r, dplyr, purrr

I'm having trouble figuring out how to use `purrr::map()` with `mutate(across(...))`.

I want to do a linear model and pull out the estimate for the slope of multiple columns as predicted by a single column.

Here is what I'm attempting with an example data set:

```
mtcars %>%
  mutate(across(-mpg), 
    map(.x, lst(slope = ~lm(.x ~ mpg, data = .x) %>% 
          tidy() %>% 
          filter(term != "(Intercept") %>% 
            pull(estimate)
  )))
```

The output I'm looking for would be new columns for each non-mpg column with _slope appended to the name, ie `cyl_slope`

In my actual data, I'll be grouping by another variable as well in case that matters, as I need the slope for each group for each predicted variable. I have this working in a standard mutate doing one variable at a time as follows:

```
df %>% 
  group_by(unitid) %>% 
  nest() %>% 

  mutate(tuition_and_fees_as_pct_total_rev_slope = map_dbl(data, ~lm(tuition_and_fees_as_pct_total_rev ~ year, data = .x) %>%
               tidy() %>%
                 filter(term == "year") %>%
                 pull(estimate)
               ))
```

So:

1. I think my issue is how to pass the column name  being predicted into the `lm`
2. I don't know if the solution requires nesting or not, so it would be appreciated if in the `mtcars` example that is considered.

Comment: In the second case, do you have a reproducible example.  The first one didn't work because 1) `across(-mpg)` closed, 2) the `data = .x` should be the original data because the `.x` is a vector

Comment: @akrun no I don't unfortunately, because I'm stuck on how to get it to work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If we wanted to do `lm` on all other columns with independent variable as 'mpg', one option is to loop over the column names of the 'mtcars' except the 'mpg', create the formula with `reformulate`, apply the `lm`, convert to a `tidy` format, `filter` out the 'Intercept' and `select` the 'estimate' column

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(broom)
map_dfc(setdiff(names(mtcars), 'mpg'), ~ 
   lm(reformulate('mpg', response = .x), data = mtcars) %>%
     tidy %>% 
     filter(term != "(Intercept)") %>%
     select(estimate))
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 1 x 10
#   estimate...1 estimate...2 estimate...3 estimate...4 estimate...5 estimate...6 estimate...7 estimate...8 estimate...9 estimate...10
#      <dbl>        <dbl>        <dbl>        <dbl>        <dbl>        <dbl>        <dbl>        <dbl>        <dbl>         <dbl>
#1       -0.253        -17.4        -8.83       0.0604       -0.141        0.124       0.0555       0.0497       0.0588        -0.148
```

---

Or this can be done more easily with a `matrix` as dependent

```
library(stringr)
lm(as.matrix(mtcars[setdiff(names(mtcars), "mpg")]) ~ mpg, 
       data = mtcars) %>% 
    tidy %>% 
    filter(term != "(Intercept)") %>%
    select(response, estimate) %>%
    mutate(response = str_c(response, '_slope'))
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 10 x 2
#   response   estimate
#   <chr>         <dbl>
# 1 cyl_slope   -0.253 
# 2 disp_slope -17.4   
# 3 hp_slope    -8.83  
# 4 drat_slope   0.0604
# 5 wt_slope    -0.141 
# 6 qsec_slope   0.124 
# 7 vs_slope     0.0555
# 8 am_slope     0.0497
# 9 gear_slope   0.0588
#10 carb_slope  -0.148
```

---

Or another option is `summarise` with `across`

```
mtcars %>%
     summarise(across(-mpg, ~ list(lm(reformulate('mpg', 
              response = cur_column())) %>%
                   tidy %>%
                   filter(term != "(Intercept)") %>%
                   pull(estimate)), .names = "{.col}_slope")) %>%
     unnest(everything())
# A tibble: 1 x 10
#  cyl_slope disp_slope hp_slope drat_slope wt_slope qsec_slope vs_slope am_slope gear_slope carb_slope
#      <dbl>      <dbl>    <dbl>      <dbl>    <dbl>      <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl>
#1    -0.253      -17.4    -8.83     0.0604   -0.141      0.124   0.0555   0.0497     0.0588     -0.148
```

Comment: Thanks.  In the actual data, it isn't all other columns which is why I am using mutate(across(...))

Comment: @jzadra you can subset to a matrix and use the same independent variable as in the update

Comment: @jzadra i updated with two more options.  Hope it works fo ryou

Comment: So your summarize version works with mutate well, the only issue is that it isn't applying the new name (concatenating the original name with the named function)

mtcars %>%
     mutate(across(-mpg, ~ list(slope = lm(reformulate('mpg', 
              response = cur_column())) %>%
                   tidy %>%
                   filter(term != "(Intercept") %>%
                   pull(estimate))))

Comment: I'm also puzzled by why I'm getting two values returned (IE why it's nested) - there shoudl only be a single value returned.

Comment: @jzadra If you new names `.names = "{.col}_slope"))`

Comment: @jzadra that is easy to explain `filter(term != "(Intercept)")` and not `filter(term != "(Intercept")`

Answer (score 2):

One option could be:

```
map_dfr(.x = names(select(mtcars, -c(mpg, vs))),
        ~ mtcars %>%
         group_by(vs) %>%
         nest() %>%
         mutate(variable = .x,
                estimate = map_dbl(data, function(y) lm(!!sym(.x) ~ mpg, data = y) %>% 
                                    tidy() %>%
                                    filter(term != "(Intercept)") %>%
                                    pull(estimate))) %>%
         select(-data))

     vs variable estimate
   <dbl> <chr>       <dbl>
 1     0 cyl       -0.242 
 2     1 cyl       -0.116 
 3     0 disp     -22.5   
 4     1 disp      -8.01  
 5     0 hp       -10.1   
 6     1 hp        -3.26  
 7     0 drat       0.0748
 8     1 drat       0.0529
 9     0 wt        -0.192 
10     1 wt        -0.113 
11     0 qsec      -0.0357
12     1 qsec      -0.0432
13     0 am         0.0742
14     1 am         0.0710
15     0 gear       0.114 
16     1 gear       0.0492
17     0 carb      -0.0883
18     1 carb      -0.0790
```